# Python: Extract HTML from an XML file

Tags: python, html, xml, lxml

My XML file looks like this:

```
 <strings>
      <string>Bla <b>One &amp; Two</b> Foo</string>
 </strings>
```

I want to extract the content of each <string> while maintaining the inner tags. That is, I would like to see the following Python string: u"Bla <b>One & Two</b> Foo". Alternatively, I guess I could settle on u"Bla <b>One & Two</b> Foo", and then try to replace the entities myself.

I am currently using lxml, which allows me to iterate over the nested tags, missing out on the text not inside a tag, or alternatively over all text content (itertext), losing the tag information. I'm probably missing something.

If possible I'd prefer to keep lxml, though I can switch to another library if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a better way of conditionally handling objects returned by the `xpath()` function, but I'm not sufficiently conversant with `lxml` to know what it is, so I had to write a function to return the text value of a node.  But that said, this shows a general approach to the problem:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> def node_text(n):
        try:
            return etree.tostring(n, method='html', with_tail=False)
        except TypeError:
            return str(n)

>>> f = StringIO('<strings><string>This is <b>not</b> how I plan to escape.</string></strings>')
>>> x = etree.parse(f)
>>> ''.join(node_text(n) for n in x.xpath('/strings/string/node()'))
'This is <b>not</b> how I plan to escape.'
```

Comment: It turns out that instead of using node(), one could also child.iterdescendants(), but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

try [etree.tostring](http://codespeak.net/lxml/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring)

```
outer = etree.tostring(string_elem, method='html')
inner = re.match("^[^>]+>(.*)<[^<]+$", outer).groups(1)[0]
```

Comment: I know about tostring actually, but that includes the string-tag itself.

Comment: wouldn't be that hard to trim out manually, a simple regex would work

Comment: +1 for finding one of the rare cases where using a regular expression to process XML isn't a terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess stripping out the surrounding tag would work well enough also.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the language, relatively simple XSLT template would do the trick.

Something like defining patterns to tags you want to keep, converting to text others.

You can of course use a recursive function with a compliant DOM implementation (minidom maybe?) and process tags by hand.

(pseudocode)

```
def Function(tag):
   if tag.NodeType = "#text": return tag.innerText
   text=""
   if tag.ElementName in allowedTags:
       text="<%s>"%tag.ElementName
   text += [Function(subtag) for subtag in tag.childs]
   if tag.ElementName in allowedTags:
       text+="</%s>"%tag.ElementName
   return text
```

Answer (score -1):

Not using parser, but just pure string manipulation

```
mystring="""
 <strings>
      <string>Bla <b>One &amp; Two</b> Foo</string>
 </strings>
"""
for s in mystring.split("</string>"):
    if "<string>" in s:
        i = s.index("<string>")
        print s[i+len("<string>"):].replace("&amp;","")
```

Comment: This list of things wrong with this approach is not short:  among others, it fails if there's an empty `<string/>` element, or if any `<string>` element contains attributes, or whitespace in its opening or closing tag, or if any text node contains character entities or CDATA.

Comment: you are assuming too much!!. And that's a bad habit.